# Which language should I use if I want to embed a simple app on a web page?

Tags: php, flash, embed

I'm thinking about setting up a website (based on WordPress) to host video tutorials on interpreting CT scans.

In addition to simply letting the visitor view PowerPoint presentation videos, I'm keen on writing some sort of simple app that I can embed in the blog to allow the visitor to scroll through a series of images (i.e. a scan).

I usually code in REALbasic or Objective-C.  I have some experience with PHP.  What are my language options for making an interactive embeddable image viewer in a blog?  The website needs to be able to be viewed on an iPad as well as normal desktop browsers.

Comment: Ugh... about the only thing worse than a powerpoint presentation is a VIDEO of a power point presentation.... gag me with a pitchfork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript.

Pick up [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), or a similar Javascript framework.  It will help you get down to business faster.

What you are asking has nothing to do with server-side coding.  It is all client-side.  Because of that, your choices are something to do with a plugin (such as Flash), or Javascript.  If you want it to work on an iPad, Flash and other plugins are out.

Answer (score 2):

Since you need your image viewer to work on the iPad, ActionScript3, hence, Flash is out of the picture. I would use JavaScript as per the examples on the Apple HTML5 advocacy site, using the canvas element to render the viewer.

Answer (score 1):

I would lean towards a javascript solution.  There are loads of libraries out there that will give you a kickstart.  If you know some example works of what you are thinking about doing, we can give you pros and cons for serverside vs. client side languages.  Additionally, you can use html5 for a lot, but then again it depends on what exactly you are wanting to do.

Comment: Basically each scan is a collection of 40-60 JPEG images. I'd like a simple interface to permit the visitor to scroll up and down through this stack of images with the mouse.